# How can I create a UITextView that expands vertically as required?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am trying to create an iphone application where I need an expandable UITextView. I am looking for something similar to a feature in contacts app for adding notes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so it should work to use the `contentSize` property to find out the dimensions of the content and resize the view accordingly. To properly react as the user edits, you should be able to use the delegate's `textViewDidChange:` method to trigger the size update.